# Evaluate integral $\int\limits_{\gamma} \sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the next integral $\int\limits_{\gamma} \sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$.

[image]

The contour is shown here:

Comment: Try substituting $w=1/z$.

Comment: You should start by understanding why there's a well-defined branch of $f(z) = \sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}$ defined along $\gamma$ (better yet, on $\Bbb C - [-1,1]$).

Comment: @Metso: Note that if you go once around the point $1$ on a circle (say), $\sqrt{z-1}$ changes by a factor of $-1$. Same if you go around $2$. If you remove the interval $[-1,1]$, then in order to go around one of the points, you must go around both, and the function changes by a factor of $(-1)(-1) = 1$, hence is well-defined. There are fancier ways to talk about this, but you should start with this. Lord Shark is suggesting that you think about the residue at $\infty$. If you've learned that, you definitely should.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: it's not clear why you take the interval  $[-1,1]$ and not $[1,2]$?

Comment: AGGGGGHHHH .. Cuz I'm used to thinking about a different problem. I can't edit. But of course I meant $[1,2]$ BOTH places. My abject apologies.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Is there a way to evaluate this integral without the residue since this is the next chapter of the book?

Comment: I'll write a sketch of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a reasonable approach. Let's make a (linear fractional) change of variables to carry $z=1$ to $w=0$ and $z=2$ to $w=\infty$. For example, you can use $w=\dfrac{z-1}{z-2}$, and the interval $[1,2]$ maps to the negative real $w$-axis. Rewrite the integral in terms of $w$ (and don't forget to change $dz$ as well). You should find
$$\int_\gamma \sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)}\,dz = -\int_\Gamma \frac{\sqrt w}{w-1}\,\frac{dw}{(w-1)^2}.$$
Now, what is $\Gamma$? You should work out for yourself that if $\gamma$ is a circle around $[1,2]$, then $\Gamma$ will be a circle that goes around $w=1$. Now you should be able to evaluate this integral by finding the Laurent series for the integrand around $w=1$. (Note that $\sqrt w$ has a well-defined branch in $\Bbb C-[-\infty,0]$.) And don't forget to keep track of which direction you go around $\Gamma$.

(Comment: The Laurent series is avoiding a direct application of the Residue Theorem, but it's equivalent, of course.)

Comment: Thank you Ted very much. The Laurent series around $w=1$ is $\frac{1}{(w-1)^3} + \frac{1}{2(w-1)^2} - \frac{1}{8(w-1)} + \frac{1}{16} + ...$.    Then  the integral is equal to $-\frac{\pi*i}{4}$. Is it correct?

Comment: I used -$\frac{1}{8}$ here.

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. (Of course, the problem never specified which branch of square root we're using, so the answer can only be $\pm$, without that information.)